# Get HTML content for non-empty elements

Tags: php, html, domdocument

Currently I have this mess, didn't ask how:

```
$string = "
<p>
    <b>Foo1:</b> Bar1<br>
    <b>Foo2:</b> Bar2<br>
    <b>Foo3:</b> Bar3<br>
    <b>Foo4:</b> Bar4
</p>
<br>
<p></p>
<br>
<p>
</br>
<br />
<br/>
<br>
</p>
"
```

So I need to trim all of this `<br>`'s and `<p>`'s like this:

```
$string = "
<p>
    <b>Foo1:</b> Bar1<br>
    <b>Foo2:</b> Bar2<br>
    <b>Foo3:</b> Bar3<br>
    <b>Foo4:</b> Bar4
</p>
"
```

I tried to do something like this:

```
$chars = " \t\n\r\0\x0B";
$subpattern = '(</?(br|p) ?/?[^>]*>)';
$pattern = '~(^'.$subpattern.'|'.$subpattern.'$)~i';

trim(preg_replace($pattern, '', $string), $chars)
```

But it removes only last `<p>`, how I can get it to work right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of parsing `HTML` with `regex`, you should use `DOMDocument`, Here we are just query `DOMDocument` with `//p/b/..`

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/788465)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$string = <<<HTML
<p>
    <b>Foo1:</b> Bar1<br>
    <b>Foo2:</b> Bar2<br>
    <b>Foo3:</b> Bar3<br>
    <b>Foo4:</b> Bar4
</p>
</p>
<br>
<p></p>
<br>
<p>
</br>
<br/ >
<br/>
<br>
</p>
HTML;
$domObject= new DOMDocument();
$domObject->loadHTML($string, LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$domXpath= new DOMXPath($domObject);
$results=$domXpath->query('//p/b/..');
foreach($results as $result)
{
    echo $domObject->saveHTML($result);
}
```

**Output:**

```
<p>
    <b>Foo1:</b> Bar1<br>
    <b>Foo2:</b> Bar2<br>
    <b>Foo3:</b> Bar3<br>
    <b>Foo4:</b> Bar4
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works flawlessly. How I can also limit max line breaks to 5? `if (++$i == 5) break;` in foreach loop didn't work for me :s

Answer (score 0):

Use strip_tags function. [Link to function description in PHP Doc.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

Comment: The OP wants to remove some tags, but not others, of the same type so I'm not sure this is a good fit.

Comment: @LornaMitchell Yes, you are right. By the way, I like very much your presentations from PHPNW :)

Comment: Well, using `strip_tags()` *could* work, but then you'd have to whitelist all the tags you want to allow, instead of just disallowing the tags you don't want. Would probably be more problematic than it helps, a regex is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying the regex approach, try parsing the HTML and then discarding the empty elements since that's actually what you want to achieve.  Something like DOMDocument::loadHTML (http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) would give you an array structure that you could loop over and then transform back to HTML once you'd removed the pieces you didn't need.

Answer (score 0):

An approach with DOMDocument and DOMXPath:

```
function isEmpty($n) {
    $nodeList = $n[0]->childNodes;
    foreach ($nodeList as $childNode) {
        switch ( $childNode->nodeType ) {
            case XML_ELEMENT_NODE:
                if ( !in_array($childNode->nodeName, ["p", "br"]) ||
                     $childNode->nodeName == "p" && !isEmpty([$childNode]) ) return false;
            case XML_TEXT_NODE:
                if ( trim($childNode->nodeValue) !== "" ) return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($string);
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$xp->registerNamespace("php", "http://php.net/xpath");
$xp->registerPHPFunctions('isEmpty');

$nodeList = $xp->query('//br[not(./ancestor::p)] | //p[php:function("isEmpty", .)]');

foreach ($nodeList as $node) {
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->childNodes as $childNode) {
    echo $dom->saveHTML($childNode);
}
```

[demo](https://eval.in/788460)